# Javascript - find latest object depending of value

Tags: javascript

I've tried to find a way to search the latest value of object, and what I found almost all using `reverse()` or by using `i-- in for loop`, but I want to avoid it somehow

I can archive it using two `var` like this:

```js
var a = [{a:true},{a:true},{a:false}]
var b = a.filter(el=>el.a == true)
console.log(b[b.length-1])
```

Is there a way to use only one var like this?

```
var a = [{a:true},{a:true},{a:false}]
a.latestValue(el=>el.a == true)
```

Comment: Why are you opposed to using `reverse()` ? It seems to be the easiest way (eg: `a.reverse().find(e => e.a)`)

Comment: Your code is fine, it is readable and does the job.

Comment: its just a simple JSObject, that i convert it to readable code, but the actual code of mine is complexity, so I want to avoid too many var just to make it work

Comment: How would you define "latest"? just index in array?

Comment: @JohanP actually i want to get the entire `object` it self

Comment: In your example, how do you know to choose the second object with `a` in it as `true` to be considered "latest".

Comment: var values = [true, true, false];

console.log(elIndex = values.length - values.reverse().indexOf(true));
console.log(values[elIndex]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically looking for something like `.find`, except a `.find` that starts at the last item and iterates backwards, rather than starting at the first item and iterating forwards. Although there are built-in functions like `lastIndexOf` (similar to `indexOf`, except starts searching from the last element) and `reduceRight` (same, but for `reduce`), no such thing exists for `.find`, so your best option is to write your own function. It's easy enough to write, doesn't mutate the original array (like `.reverse()` does) and doesn't require creating an intermediate array:

```js
function findRight(arr, callback) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i--; i >= 0) {
    if (callback(arr[i], i, arr)) return arr[i];
  }
}

var a = [{id: 1, a:true},{id: 2, a:true},{id: 3, a:false}];
console.log(
  findRight(a, el => el.a === true)
);
```

I guess it would be possible to (ab)use `reduceRight` for this, though I wouldn't recommend it:

```js
var a = [{id: 1, a:true},{id: 2, a:true},{id: 3, a:false}];
console.log(
  a.reduceRight((a, el) => a || (el.a && el), null)
);
```

Comment: is there the only recommended way to use `reverse()` or `for loop`?

Comment: `reverse` is not a good idea because if you call it on the original array, it will mutate the original array, and if you call it on the intermediate array, that means that you've created an (unnecessary) intermediate array. There's nothing at all wrong with using a `for` loop. I'm sure one can imagine other ways to achieve this, but the `for` loop really is the fastest and most straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

use `find` to get only one match.

If you don't like the order, you can `reverse` it, too.

```js
var a = [{
    a:true,
    id: 1
},{
    a:true,
    id: 2,
},{
    a:false,
    id: 3
}]

const latestValue = a.find(el => el.a === true)
const lastValue = a.reverse().find(el => el.a === true)

console.log(latestValue);
console.log(lastValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know already answered but thought it can be achieved in a different way, So here is my solution
You can use JavaScript array map function to get the index of latest value like this

NOTE : I have modified your array to contain more elements

```
var a = [{a:true},{a:true},{a:false},{a:false},{a:false},{a:true},{a:true},{a:false}];

var latestIndexOfTrue = a.map(function(e) { return e.a; }).lastIndexOf(true)
console.log(latestIndexOfTrue);

  /* above will give you the last index of the value you want (here i have tried with 
  * value true) and it will give you the index as 6 */
```

if you want whole object then you can get it with bellow code

```
console.log(a[latestIndexOfTrue]);
```